# How to initialize only few elements of an array with some values?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

Is it possible to assign **some** values to an array instead of all? To clarify what I want:

If I need an array like `{1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0}` I can create it like:

```
int array[] = {1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0};
```

Most values of this array are '0'. Is it possible to skip this values and only assign the values 1, 2 and 3? I think of something like:

```
int array[12] = {0: 1, 4: 2, 8: 3};
```

Comment: It depends on how do you populate your array. Do you know where the valid indexes upfront?

Comment: BTW, this is intialization and not assignment. Assignment to arrays is not possible in C and C++.

Comment: same question but for java can somebody adddress that?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

> Is it possible to skip this values and only assign the values 1, 2 and 3?

In C, Yes. Use designated initializer (added in C99 and not supported in C++).

```
int array[12] = {[0] = 1, [4] = 2, [8] = 3};
```

Above initializer will initialize element `0`, `4` and `8` of array `array` with values `1`, `2` and `3` respectively. Rest elements will be initialized with `0`. This will be equivalent to

```
 int array[12] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0};
```

The best part is that the order in which elements are listed doesn't matter. One can also write like

```
 int array[12] = {[8] = 3, [0] = 1, [4] = 2};
```

But note that the expression inside `[ ]` shall be an *integer constant expression*.

Comment: This is exactly what I searched. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @WhiZTiM designated initializers is C not C++

Comment: Could you tell me a variant of that which allows you to initialize all values of an array to a single value.

Comment: Nice approach! Can we use unknown values for the indexes? Something like `{[i] = 1, [j] = 2, [k] = 3};` where `i`, `j`, and `k` are to be assigned on run time?

Comment: Nvm my comment, I will just use `fill`

Comment: @FirstStep You deal with noncostant array index in initializer. So the answer is no.

Comment: Interesting to see something supported by C but not C++, given that C++ was supposed to be backwards compatible with C.

Comment: @ray C++ is not compatible with C. They do have common subset, but even there, there are many differences. Also there are many, many things in C which are not supported in C++. Just look at C11.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: I said it *was* supposed to be b/c that's how it had actually started.

Comment: For c++ how about just using int array[12] = {0}; {[8] = 3; [0] = 1; [4] = 2;} I know ist just plain code but is almost identical

Comment: @FirstStep; No. They must be some integer constants.

Comment: @Kennet; No. Will not work. Unfortunately there is no equivalent for c designated initializer in c++

Comment: Ups. Yes of cause. That was a bit to fast.

Comment: @Christophe If you are programming C with a compiler that only supports *decades* old archaic version of the language (C89), then lack of designated initializers is probably least of your headaches... ;-)

Comment: @hyde sorry I thought it was a c++ question and tried c++14 conformance with an uptodate compiler...

Comment: @FirstStep True constants are only with `define` so [This is ok](http://ideone.com/DHz9mc) , but [This is wrong](http://ideone.com/w0YAbJ).

Comment: Looks like the black sheep doesn't support this. 

Comment: @Daniel Didn't get it?

Comment: @haccks: I meant C++

Answer (score 13):

Here is my trivial approach:

```
int array[12] = {0};
array[0] = 1; array[4] = 2; array[8] = 3;
```

However, technically speaking, this is not "initializing" the array :)

Answer (score 6):

An alternative way to do it would be to give default value by `memset` for all elements in the array, and then assign the specific elements:

```
int array[12];
memset(array, 0, sizeof(int) * 12); //if the default value is 0, this may not be needed
array[0] = 1; array[4] = 2; array[8] = 3;
```

Comment: What is wrong with `memset(array, 0, sizeof array);` ?

Comment: that's ok actually. using `sizeof(data_type) * data_type_size` - Just my habit... :)

Answer (score 1):

### Standard C17

The standard (C17, N2176) has an interesting example in § 6.7.9(37):

> **EXAMPLE 13** Space can be “allocated” from both ends of an array by using a single designator:
>
> ```
> int a[MAX] = {
>     1, 3, 5, 7, 9, [MAX-5] = 8, 6, 4, 2, 0
> };
> ```
>
> In the above, if `MAX` is greater than ten, there will be some
>   zero-valued elements in the middle; if it is less than ten, some of
>   the values provided by the first five initializers will be overridden
>   by the second five.

### Example

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 12

int main(void)
{
    // n2176, § 6.7.9(37)
    int a[MAX] = {
        1, 3, 5, 7, 9, [MAX-5] = 8, 6, 4, 2, 0
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
1
3
5
7
9
0  <-- middle element, defaults to zero
0  <-- middle element, defaults to zero
8
6
4
2
0
```