# What do square brackets arround an enum mean? [enum_value]

Tags: c, enums, brackets

I'm currently wrapping my head around *proper* state machines, and I've found this article which seemed to be exactly what I've been searching for:
https://aticleworld.com/state-machine-using-c/
In the process of understanding table of the table based state machine I've stumbled over this piece of code which in my opinion is quite hard to read.

So this is as far as I can come:

- eSystemState is a typedefed enum which indicates the current state.
- eSystemEvent is a typedefed enum which indicates the current event.
- pfEventHandler is a typedefed function pointer returning eSystemState.
- afEventHandler is a typedefed, two dimensional array (limited by "last_State" and "last_Event") of function pointers returning eSystemState.

Next up are some event handlers for each type of event.
Then beginning of main, some initialization and there it comes.

The previously defined type afEventHandler gets filled with content, but the operations which are used there are a big mystery to me.

I know that for every curly brackets a new 'row' gets filled, but what do the square brackets around the enums mean, and why can one apparently assign a value to whatever comes out of this?

I know that enums are essentially numbers, and I suspect it is some (to me) super obscure way to address a specific element in an array.

Am I wrong?

```
 // Table to define valid states and event of finite state machine
 static afEventHandler StateMachine = {
 [Idle_State] ={[Card_Insert_Event]= InsertCardHandler },
 [Card_Inserted_State] ={[Pin_Enter_Event] = EnterPinHandler },
 [Pin_Eentered_State] ={[Option_Selection_Event] = OptionSelectionHandler},
 [Option_Selected_State] ={[Amount_Enter_Event] = EnterAmountHandler},
 [Amount_Entered_State] ={[Amount_Dispatch_Event] = AmountDispatchHandler}, 
 };
```

Comment: The difference between my question and that "duplicate" is that i had no idea what the code does and the train of thought is the other way around. People who face the same situation as i have will certainly not randomly search for "designated initializer".

Comment: So, your question will survive and provide useful search material while the duplicate link will lead the searcher to a full answer.

Answer (score 7):

This syntax is for a **designated initializer**.  It allows you to initialize specific elements of an array.

The value in square brackets is the index of the array element to initialize.  In this case it is an enum value, but itcould be any integer.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets mark array subscripts. The `enum` identifiers inside them are simply ordinary expressions, replaced by the `enum` values.

C allows you to initialize arrays using explicit subscripts, called *designators*. For example, this initialize `A[1]` to 4:

```
int A[3] = { [1] = 4 };
```

(The other elements default to zero.)

With a two-dimensional array, the syntax gets more complicated:

```
int B[3][4] =
{
    [1] = { [3] = 7 }
};
```

That initializes `B[1][3]` to 7. That is the syntax you are seeing in the code you refer to. It then uses `enum` identifiers like `Idle_State` instead of the sample constants `1`, `3`, and `7` shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it myself, it's a "**designated initializer**" which indeed specifies which element shall be set by a chosen value.

It's been introduced in C99 which explains why i didn't know about it. Other elements get initialized to 0.

I'll leave the question here for others who may wonder about the same.
[How to initialize only few elements of an array with some values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860046/how-to-initialize-only-few-elements-of-an-array-with-some-values)

```
int a[10][10] = {
{},
{[5] = 8}
};
```

Means that in the second row the element 5 is gonna be initialized to eight, others will be zero.