# Specifying specific values in an array initialization

Tags: c#, array-initialization

I recall that in C# a notation similar to the one below would be a correct array initializer.

```
int[] array = new int[3]
{
  [1] = 5;
};
```

This should initialize the array with all values as default (0 in the case of int) and assign 5 to index 1.

The equivalent would be

```
int[] array = {0, 5, 0};
```

This would be correct with a type other than int[] that implements an indexer, but how would I do it with an array?

Comment: You mean [C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38860092/1997232) with first snippet, don't you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All possible array initialization syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-array-initialization-syntaxes)

Comment: That is exactly what I remember. So.. it works in C, but not C# I guess

Comment: @prenone exactly in C# there isn't that type of initialization, in this case you can solve in the way you have already done or set the value right after the initialization.

Comment: Okay, that is what I was afraid of. Thank you very much for clarifying